# Libraries for converting physical units (kilograms, pounds) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, physics, dsl, units-of-measurement

I know Rails has some nice helpers for date and time management. Is there an already-working project consisting of, or incorporating a clean DSL for standard units and their conversions? Any project with helpers for the conversion between the two systems' basic units of length and weight would work. Thank you!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Wow, there are quite a few more of these than I expected. Here is what I believe to be a complete list, in alphabetical order, with example usage stripped from their documentation. I also noted if I couldn't get them running locally.

1. [Alchemist](https://github.com/halogenandtoast/alchemist)

   ```
   require 'alchemist'
   Alchemist.setup
   8.miles.to.meters
   10.kilometers + 1.mile # 11.609344 kilometers
   ```
2. [measurement](https://github.com/collectiveidea/measurement)

   This one appears out of date, the last commit was 5 years ago, and it doesn't seem to run on 1.9.3 for me.

   ```
   include Measurement::Length
   Inch.new(12).to_centimeters # => #<Measurement::Length::Centimeter:0x173c2b4 @units=30.48>
   ```
3. [Phys-Units](https://github.com/masa16/phys-units)

   ```
   require "phys/units"
   Q = Phys::Quantity
   U = Phys::Unit

   Q[1.23,'km'] + Q[4.56,'m']    #=> Phys::Quantity[1.23456,'km']
   Q[123,'mile'] / Q[2,'hr']     #=> Phys::Quantity[61,'mile/hr']
   Q[61,'miles/hr'].want('m/s')  #=> Phys::Quantity[27.26944,'m/s']
   Q[1.0,'are'] == Q[10,'m']**2  #=> true
   ```
4. [Quantity](https://github.com/bhuga/quantity)

   Note that this one states that it is not production ready in the README.

   ```
   require 'quantity/all'
   1.meter                                         #=> 1 meter
   1.meter.to_feet                                 #=> 3.28083... foot
   c = 299792458.meters / 1.second                 #=> 299792458 meter/second

   newton = 1.meter * 1.kilogram / 1.second**2     #=> 1 meter*kilogram/second^2
   newton.to_feet                                  #=> 3.28083989501312 foot*kilogram/second^2
   newton.convert(:feet)                                   #=> 3.28083989501312 foot*kilogram/second^2
   jerk_newton = newton / 1.second                         #=> 1 meter*kilogram/second^3
   jerk_newton * 1.second == newton                        #=> true
   ```
5. [SY](https://github.com/boris-s/sy)

   See [Boris Stitnickey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16627272/1406964).
6. [ruby-measurement](https://github.com/mhuggins/ruby-measurement)

   ```
   require 'ruby-measurement'

   measurement = Measurement.parse('3 feet')  # => 3.0 ft.
   measurement.convert_to(:yards)             # => 1.0 yd.
   measurement.convert_to(:in)                # => 36.0 in.
   measurement.convert_to(:inches)            # => 36.0 in.

   measurement1 = Measurement.parse('3 feet') # => 3.0 ft.
   measurement2 = Measurement.parse('6 inch') # => 6.0 in.
   measurement1 + measurement2                # => 3.5 ft.
   ```
7. [ruby-units](https://github.com/olbrich/ruby-units)

   ```
   require 'ruby-units'

   unit = Unit("mm")                # unit only (defaults to a scalar of 1)
   unit = Unit("1 mm")              # create a simple unit
   unit = Unit("1 kg*m^2/s^2")      # complex unit

   unit1 =~ unit2                   # true if units are compatible
   unit1.compatible?(unit2)         # true if units are compatible

   unit1 = unit >> "ft"             # convert to 'feet'
   unit3 = unit1 + unit2            # resulting object will have the units of unit1

   unit1 === unit2                  # true if units and quantity are the same, even if 'equivalent' by <=>
   unit.convert_to('ft')            # convert
   (unit1 + unit2).convert_to('ft') # converts result to 'ft'
   ```
8. [Units for Ruby](https://github.com/bfoz/units-ruby)

   ```
   require 'units'

   three_meters = 3.meters
   two_meters = 2.m
   one_inch = 1.inch

   3.meters.to_inches # => 118.1103 inch
   10.inches.to_mm    # => 254.0 millimeter
   ```
9. [Unitwise](https://github.com/joshwlewis/unitwise)

   ```
   require 'unitwise/ext'

   1.yard == (1.foot * 3)                       # => true

   1.quart < 1.liter                            # => true

   2.meter + 3.inch - 1.yard                    # => <Unitwise::Measurement 1.1618 meter>

   1.convert_to('kg.m2/s2') == 1.joule          # => true

   (20.kg * 9.8.convert_to('m/s2')).to_pound_force # => <Unitwise::Measurement 44.06255284754326 pound_force>

   (300.horsepower * 60.second).to_calorie      # => <Unitwise::Measurement 3208077.8414151203 calorie>
   ```
10. [Van/Unit](http://rubyworks.github.com/vanunits/)

    Like another poster, I had trouble getting this working. However, you can see [Jörg W Mittag's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4235807/1406964) for usage.

As the author of [Unitwise](https://github.com/joshwlewis/unitwise), it might be obvious that it's my favorite out of the group. I encourage you to at least check it out, though.

Comment: In [Phys-Units](https://github.com/masa16/phys-units), which is allegedly a Ruby implementation of [GNU Units](https://www.gnu.org/software/units/), a handy mixin is available with `require 'phys/units/mixin'`; eg., `((1.hr+11.min+12.s) >> min).value.to_f` gives 71.2.

Answer (score 6):

Try awesome [Alchemist](https://github.com/halogenandtoast/alchemist).

......

Comment: Thanks and +1, looks extremely nice.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Tom Sawyer's [Van/Unit](http://RubyWorks.GitHub.Com/vanunits/)

This is from the homepage:

```
require 'van/units'
include Units

1.mile.to(feet)
1.acre.to(yd**2)
1.acre.to(sq_yd)
1.gallon.to(self.L)
1.lb.to(kg)
1.m.s.to(m.s)
1.sq_mi.to(km**2)
1.mile.to(km)
1.usd.to(twd)
1.bit/s + 8.bytes/s
```

Comment: Gorgeous. This is exactly what I was secretly hoping for. Thank you! +1 and accepted

Answer (score 1):

Try `gem install sy`

```
require 'sy'

( 5.g *                # a bullet of 5g
    500.m.s(-1) ** 2 / # flying at a speed of 500m/s has kJ energy:
2 ).in( :kJ )          #=> 0.625

require 'sy/imperial'    

1.mile.in :ft   #=> 5280.0
1.acre.in :yd²  #=> 4840.0
1.gallon.in :l  #=> 4.54609
1.lb.in :kg     #=> 0.45359237
1.mile².in :km² #=> 2.589988110336
SY::SPEED_OF_LIGHT.in "furlong.fortnight⁻¹" #=> 1802617499785.2544
```

Comment: In [sy](https://github.com/boris-s/sy), I emphasize business model correctness and ease of use over ease of implementation. The only other physical units library apart from _sy_, whose object model I really like, is [phys-units](https://github.com/masa16/phys-units) from [the author of famous narray gem](https://github.com/masa16).

Comment: +1/accepting this as it seems significantly more modern/maintained than the previous suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get Van/units to work - all it reports is:

> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vanunits-1.5.0/lib/van/units/base.rb:493:in
>   `to': incompatible units for operation
>   (TypeError)
>           from unitstest.rb:4

When running

```
require 'rubygems' 
require 'van/units' 
include Van::Units puts
1.meter.to(feet)
```

I spent an hour unsuccessfully attempting to hack the source of van/units.

The older gem on which it is based worked out of the box:

http://ruby-units.rubyforge.org/ruby-units/

Answer (score 0):

vanunits seems broken. i suggest to try

rubyunits (http://ruby-units.rubyforge.org/ruby-units/)

or

measurements (https://github.com/collectiveidea/measurement)